# How to retrieve an integer value in Java from MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab

I wish to perform the following task: I am calling MATLAB function using matlabcontrol in Java, where I'm passing a value (say `X` of integer type) from java to MATLAB. However, I want to make some changes (`X = X + 3`) in MATLAB and wish to retrieve the updated value in Java only.

In Java (using matlabcontrol):

```
proxy.setVariable("X", timestamp);
proxy.eval("X");
double result = ((double[]) proxy.getVariable("X"))[0];
System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

I also know that we can execute a value in MATLAB from Java.

```
import com.mathworks.jmi.*
Matlab.mtEval('X + 3',1)
```

I can see the correct result on MATLAB terminal. However, I am not able to send the result back to the Java. Any help in this regard is appreciated!